# Why does putting a margin on one div move its container?

Tags: html, css

I've a container div which has another div inside it. When I apply a margin to the inner div it appears to a margin-top to the container div (although it doesn't give a left margin)

http://belfastswimmingteacher.com/mockup.html

What's the craic?

Comment: Links to other sites may be a good *adjunct* to a question, but always post the relevant code/markup *in the question* as well. Two reasons. 1. People shouldn't have to follow a link to help you. 2. StackOverflow is meant to be a resource not just for you now, but for others having a similar issue in the future. External links can get moved, modified, deleted, etc. By making sure the relevant code is in the question, we ensure that the question (and its answers) remain useful for a reasonable period of time.

Comment: apologies, I'll remember that for the future.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can either float the `halfLeft` div, or add `padding-top` to `#content`.

This is known as [margin collapsing](http://www.google.co.uk/search?sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=margin%20collapsing), and whilst may produce this unwanted behaviour, is in fact intended and correct.